# Why doesn't my content field match my MAX(id) field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a subset of data based on the latest id and dates.  It seems that when selecting other fields in the table they are not in sync with the max id and dates returned.

Any idea how I can fix this?

MySQL:

```
SELECT MAX(m.id) as id, m.sender_id, m.receiver_id, MAX(m.date) as date, m.content, l.username, p.gender 
FROM  messages m 
LEFT JOIN login_users l on l.user_id = m.sender_id 
LEFT JOIN profiles p ON p.user_id = l.user_id 
WHERE m.receiver_id=3
GROUP BY m.sender_id ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 7
```

The data for content isn't the correct one. It seems to be returning random content and not the content that is tied to the row for max id and max date.

Do I need to do some sort of sub select to fix this?

Comment: There is no reason they should match. In most flavours of SQL having non aggregate fields that are not in the GROUP BY field would just give you an error. MySQL doesn't enforce this, but which row the fields come from is undefined.

Comment: Read this to understand better why your usage of `GROUP BY` is incorrect: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html and this: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question in the title, "Why doesn't my content field match my MAX(id) field", that's because there is no guarantee that the values returned for the non-aggregate fields will be from the row where the MAX value is found. This is the documented behavior, and this is what we expect.

Other DBMS would throw an error on the statement, MySQL is just more lax, and you are getting values from one row, but it's not guaranteed to be the row that either of the MAX values (id or date) is found on.

You have two separate aggregate expression `MAX(m.id)` and `MAX(m.date)`. Note that there is no guarantee that those values will come from the same row.

The rule in other databases is that every non-aggregate expression in the SELECT list needs to appear in the GROUP BY. (MySQL is more lax about that, and doesn't make that a requirement.)

One way to "fix" the query so that it does return values from the row with the MAX value is to use an inline view (query) that gets the `MAX(id)` grouped by what you want to GROUP BY, and then a JOIN back to the original table to get other values on the row.

From your statement it's not clear what result set you want returned. If you want the row that has the maximum id and you also want the row with maximum date, then you could something like this:

```
SELECT m.id
     , m.sender_id
     , m.receiver_id
     , m.date
     , m.content
     , l.username
     , p.gender 
  FROM ( SELECT t.sender_id
              , t.receiver_id
              , MAX(t.id) AS max_id
              , MAX(t.date) AS max_date
           FROM messages t
          WHERE t.receiver_id=3
          GROUP
             BY t.sender_id
              , t.receiver_id
       ) s
  JOIN messages m 
    ON m.sender_id = s.sender_id
   AND m.receiver_id = s.receiver_id
   AND ( m.id = s.max_id OR m.date = s.max_date)
  LEFT
  JOIN login_users l on l.user_id = m.sender_id 
  LEFT
  JOIN profiles p ON p.user_id = l.user_id
 ORDER BY m.date DESC LIMIT 0, 7
```

The inline view aliased as "s" returns the max values, and then that gets joined back to the messages table, aliased as "m".

**NOTE**

In most cases, we find that a `JOIN (query)` will perform better than an `IN (query)`, because of the different access plans. You can see the difference in plans with an EXPLAIN.

For performance, you'll want an index

```
... ON messages (`receiver_id`, `sender_id`, `id`, `date`)
```

There's an equality predicate on receiver_id, so that should be the leading column, to get a range scan (instead of a full scan). You want the `sender_id` column next, because that should allow MySQL to avoid a "Using filesort" operation to get the rows grouped. The `id` and `date` columns are included, so that the inline view query can be satisfied entirely from the index pages without a need to access the pages in the table. (The EXPLAIN should show "`Using where; Using index`".)

That same index should also suitable for the outer query, though it does need to access the "`content`" column from the table pages, so the EXPLAIN will not show "Using index" for that step. (It's likely that the "`content`" column is much longer than we would want in the index.)

Comment: I get this error: Unknown column 's.receiver_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: @Paul: the query is updated. i removed that predicate, it doesn't need to be there.

Comment: @Paul: I readded the predicate, and included `receiver_id` in the SELECT list and GROUP BY of the inline view. Without that, I don't think there's a guarantee that the outer query will return only rows associated with receiver_id=3. (The other option would be to add a `WHERE m.receiver_id = 3` on the outermost query.) BUt it really depends on what you want returned.

Comment: hmm...all of these queries are killing my server, timing out because they take so long.  The messages table has nearly 400k records.  My current statement takes just a fraction of a second. Should I maybe perform two queries to get the correct content record?

Comment: @Paul: no. its likely that you don't have suitable indexes on your `messages` table. For this query, you'd want an index defined `ON messages (receiver_id, sender_id, id, date)`.

Comment: If you don't need to get both rows, the one with the highest id, and the one with the latest date, then you could omit one of those MAX aggregates.  (The original query had both `MAX(date)` and `MAX(id)`, and those could come from two different rows. If you have some special domain knowledge that the MAX values for both of those will occur on the same row, and you only need to return that one row, then you can omit one of those MAX aggregates from the inline view, and remove the associated join predicate from the outer query.

Comment: Thanks for the udpdate and the tip for indexes, works much better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *could* probably solve it without a subselect, but doing one is fairly straight forward. Something like this should work, just make the subselect return the id's of the interesting rows in messages, and get the data for only them.

```
SELECT m.id as id, m.sender_id, m.receiver_id, m.date as date, 
       m.content, l.username, p.gender 
FROM  messages m 
LEFT JOIN login_users l on l.user_id = m.sender_id 
LEFT JOIN profiles p ON p.user_id = l.user_id 
WHERE m.id IN (
  SELECT max(id) FROM messages
  WHERE receiver_id=3
  GROUP BY sender_id
)
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 7
```

The reason that your original query does not match up fields is that `GROUP BY` really requires aggregate functions (like MAX/MIN/SUM/...) applied to every field you select that's not grouped by. The reason the query even runs is that MySQL does not enforce that, but instead returns indeterminate fields from any row that is matching. Afaik, all other SQL RDBMS' refuse to run the query.

EDIT: As for performance, a few indexes that are likely to help are;

```
CREATE INDEX ix_inner ON messages(receiver_id, sender_id, id);
CREATE INDEX ix_login_users ON login_users(user_id);
CREATE INDEX ix_profiles ON profiles(user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a join

```
SELECT LatestM.id, m.sender_id, m.receiver_id, m.date, m.content, l.username, p.gender 
(
    SELECT sender_id, MAX(id) AS id
    FROM  messages 
    WHERE receiver_id=3
    GROUP BY sender_id 
) LatestM
INNER JOIN messages m 
ON LatestM.sender_id = m.sender_id AND LatestM.id = m.id
LEFT JOIN login_users l on l.user_id = m.sender_id 
LEFT JOIN profiles p ON p.user_id = l.user_id 
WHERE m.receiver_id = 3
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 7
```

Problem with this is that if the latest id does not reflect the latest date then the date returned will not be the latest one.